# Variable pulled from DB not working in a function

Tags: php, arrays

Cannot get my head around why a variable pulled from a db is not working.

I have an array that I am searching using array_search().

Using the function like so:

```
$band2 = taxBandtoPrice2("$car->tax_band");
echo "(£$band2 Per Year)";
```

Note, "$car->tax_band" is a query that takes the tax_band value. This part works for a certain.

$band2 is always blank. If i replace "$car->tax_band" with 'c' it works fine.

How should I be doing this where might I be going wrong?

The function itself:

```
function taxBandtoPrice2($taxband){
  $bands = array(
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    ...
  );
  $key = array_search($taxband, $bands);
  return $key;
}
```

Comment: print_r($car) and check whether tax_band is coming or not in the array.

Comment: Why are there `"` characters around `$car->tax_band`? Do you really want to pass it as string?

Comment: @bali182 even if I remove the " it stills return nothing. Ill see what print returns.

Comment: Also, if in the function i return the $taxband variable I pass in, it does return the passed in value so its not that thats the issue...

Comment: because $car->tax_band its not has any value probably.

Comment: `var_dump($car->tax_band)` shows anything?

Comment: $car->tax_band is okay. Its used many times before this function. It is passed into the function okay and I can see that by returning the passed in variable.

Comment: could u please show us the output for : `print_r($car)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it should work. You can try following changes:

```
$band2 = taxBandtoPrice2($car->tax_band);
echo "(£{$band2} Per Year)";
```

Ensure with `var_dump($car->tax_band)` and later with `var_dump($band2)` what values **and types** are. What can I think off are two reasons:

1. `$car->tax_band` is not equal to values in `$bands`. Even a single
   space and lower/uppercase makes difference.
2. List item `$car->tax_band` gets
   overwritten before passed to function.

Comment: var_dump returns: string(1) "C" so does $band2

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix for me on this one.

I was passing in a C but the values in my array were in lower case...

I changed the value to a lowercase with

```
strtolower();
```